# Configuring java policy file with Wildfly 8.1

Tags: java, security, wildfly

When running my application in wildfly 8.1, I'm getting an AccessControlException:

```
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "uka.karmi.useDistributedThreads" "read")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:457 [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(SecurityManager.java:1294) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
at java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:714) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
```

I'm running my wildfly server with VM argument:

```
-Djava.security.policy=/opt/misc/test.policy
```

Where test.policy looks like:

```
grant {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

I also tried modifying test.policy:

```
grant {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "uka.karmi.useDistributedThreads", "read";
};
```

but still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way for defining deployment permissions in the WildFly is by `META-INF/permissions.xml` (or vendor specific `META-INF/jboss-permissions.xml`) file, which is comming with Java EE 7.

The problem is, WildFly seems to have [an issue (WFLY-3651)](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-3651) with it.

The `permissions.xml` file in your case could look like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<permissions xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/permissions_7.xsd"
    version="7">
    <permission>
        <class-name>java.util.PropertyPermission</class-name>
        <name>uka.karmi.useDistributedThreads</name>
        <actions>read</actions>
    </permission>
</permissions>
```